# Vertex Group in Geometry nodes set to another object

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry, vertex-groups

I am trying to use Geometry nodes to control the position of a vertex group I have.  I am able to recall the group and I am able to move it but I want the vertex group to be assigned to either a point or the end of a mesh line.

For more context I am working on a parametric door and I want to be able to create the door elements as their own objects and then reference them in the geometry nodes through a collection. This does work but without asigning the vertex group to something, I have to "squish" the model together to get it to work the way I want. Its not as intuitive or practical.

[image: Squished Model]

[image: Desired Outcome]

Hopefully this makes sense.  Any Ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: If you share your project with https://blend-exchange.com/ it will be easer to help you.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=BsDJ4VLp" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/BsDJ4VLp/)

Comment: Okay, I think I found the answer I was knd of looking for, but now I am stuck with another problem. I found that I needed to use a bounding box to extract the overall dimension of the door slab and I used that number and a math node to minus the X-axis and the input value can then be used to size the door what I want. 

Problem is now, I need a way to get the middle vertex goup to move half the distance of the width value. Also, how I can combine these set position nodes so I can manipulate the values independently to one model. 

Below is another file that has the updated nodes.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=sp7dwnWO" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/sp7dwnWO/)

Comment: I don't quite understand what your problem is.
I downloaded your file but it is huge and complex.
The ideal so that someone can help you is to make a file with only what is necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad.  There are two tests in those files where the first was to create a parametric door only using geometry nodes but as you mentioned, its a large file. That why I want to figure out a way to control the door using collections of premade models instead. I will add the reduced file here:

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=1XRBoq9y" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/1XRBoq9y/)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how can we help you.
Perhaps a solution is to make a new blend project with a door more easily. My level of English is not very good and perhaps it's me who can't understand you.